# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error - when launching Flask app

Tags: python, flask, nlp

I'm trying to launch this flask app but i get this error when `app.run(Debug=True)` executes. The error stack is below the code.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect, url_for,  send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import sys
import numpy as np
import os.path
import getopt
from cStringIO import StringIO
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import en_coref_md
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from skip_thoughts import configuration
from skip_thoughts import encoder_manager
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import networkx as nx

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path_to_uploads/Uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

model = None
nlp = None

@app.route('/load', methods=['GET'])
def _load_model():
    model = load_model()
    return True

def load_model():
    nlp = en_coref_md.load()
    print "coref model loaded"

    VOCAB_FILE = "skip_thoughts_uni/vocab.txt"
    EMBEDDING_MATRIX_FILE = "skip_thoughts_uni/embeddings.npy"
    CHECKPOINT_PATH = "skip_thoughts_uni/model.ckpt-501424"
    encoder = encoder_manager.EncoderManager()
    print "loading skip model"
    encoder.load_model(configuration.model_config(),
                        vocabulary_file=VOCAB_FILE,
                        embedding_matrix_file=EMBEDDING_MATRIX_FILE,
                        checkpoint_path=CHECKPOINT_PATH)
    print "loaded"
    return encoder,nlp

def convertpdf (fname, pages=None):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        pagenums = set(pages)

    output = StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    infile = file(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close
    return text 

def readfiles (file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()
    return contents

def preprocess (data):
    data = data.replace("\n", "")
    data = data.replace(".", ". ")
    sentences = ""
    for s in sent_tokenize(data):
        sentences= sentences + str(s.strip()) + " "
    return sentences

def coref_resolution (data,nlp):
    sent = unicode(data, "utf-8")
    doc = nlp(sent)
    if(doc._.has_coref):
        data = str(doc._.coref_resolved)
    return data

def generate_embed (encoder,data):
    sent = sent_tokenize(data)
    embed = encoder.encode(sent)
    x = np.isnan(embed)
    if (x.any() == True):
        embed = Imputer().fit_transform(embed)
    return sent, embed

def cluster (embed,n):
    n_clusters = int(np.ceil(n*0.33))
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=0)
    kmeans = kmeans.fit(embed)

    array = []
    for j in range(n_clusters):
        array.append(list(np.where(kmeans.labels_ == j)))

    arr= []
    for i in range (n_clusters):
        ratio = float(len(array[i][0]))/float(n)
        sent_num = int(np.ceil(float(len(array[i][0]))*ratio))
        if (sent_num > 0):
            arr.append([i,sent_num])

    return array,arr

def sent_select (arr, array, sentences,embed):
    selected = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        sentences_x = []
        for j in range(len(array[arr[i][0]][0])):
                    sentences_x.append(sentences[array[arr[i][0]][0][j]])

        sim_mat = np.zeros([len(array[arr[i][0]][0]), len(array[arr[i][0]][0])])
        for k in range(len(array[arr[i][0]][0])):
            for l in range(len(array[arr[i][0]][0])):
                if k != l:
                    sim_mat[k][l] = cosine_similarity(embed[k].reshape(1,2400), embed[l].reshape(1,2400))

        nx_graph = nx.from_numpy_array(sim_mat)
        scores = nx.pagerank(nx_graph)
        ranked = sorted(scores)
        x = arr[i][1]  
        for p in range(x):
                selected.append(sentences_x[ranked[p]])

    return selected


def generate_summary(encoder,text):
    sent, embed = generate_embed(encoder,text)
    array , arr = cluster(embed, len(sent))
    selected = sent_select (arr,array,sent,embed)
    summary = ""
    for x in range(len(selected)):
        try:
            summary = summary + selected[x].encode('utf-8') + " "
        except:
            summary = summary + str(selected[x]) + " "
    try:
        sum_sent = sent_tokenize(summary.decode('utf-8'))
    except:
        sum_sent = sent_tokenize(summary)


        summary = ""
        for s in sent:
            for se in sum_sent:
                if (se == s):
                    try:
                        summary = summary + se.encode('utf-8') + " "
                    except:
                        summary = summary + str(se) + " "
        return summary


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/single-summary', methods=['POST'])
def singleFileInput():
    print(request.files['singleFile'])
    file = request.files['singleFile']

    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    uploaded_file_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)
    text = ""
    # for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    if(".pdf" in uploaded_file_path):
        t = convertpdf(uploaded_file_path)
        t = preprocess(t)
        t = coref_resolution(t, nlp)
        text = text + t
    elif(".txt" in uploaded_file_path):
        t = readfiles(uploaded_file_path)
        t = preprocess(t)
        t = coref_resolution(t, nlp)
        text = text + t
    summary = generate_summary(model,text)
    return summary


@app.route('/multiple-summary', methods=['POST'])
def multipleFileInput():
    print(request.files['multipleFile'])
    file = request.files['multipleFile']

    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    uploaded_file_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)
    text = ""
    # for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    if(".pdf" in uploaded_file_path):
        t = convertpdf(uploaded_file_path)
        t = preprocess(t)
        t = coref_resolution(t, nlp)
        text = text + t
    elif(".txt" in uploaded_file_path):
        t = readfiles(uploaded_file_path)
        t = preprocess(t)
        t = coref_resolution(t, nlp)
        text = text + t
    summary = generate_summary(model,text)
    return summary

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            #return uploaded_file(filename)
            # return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
            #                         filename=filename))
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global model
    global nlp
    model, nlp = load_model()

    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the error trace stack:

```
  File "app.py", line 251, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "/directory_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/directory_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 988, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "/directory_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
  File "/directory_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Any idea why this error is showing? This didn't show when i ran this on my own laptop. Now i'm doing it on a more powerful desktop since the model loading function kills my laptop.

Comment: Did you copy any files from the laptop to the desktop?  What OS does each computer use?

Comment: @John Gordon My laptop has Ubuntu 18.0.4 and the desktop Ubuntu 16

Comment: Did you copy any binary files (`.pyc` files, executables, etc.) from the laptop to the desktop?

Comment: @John Gordon yeah, I did. If that's the problem how can I fix it?

Comment: Remove and re-create those files on the desktop, using the same process you originally used on the laptop.